# Side-by-side box plots of data (in one plot) in R

Tags: r, boxplot

```
boxplot(s2040_W20_fishjump$Distance, main = "Fish Jump Distance", xlab = "Control vs Treatment", ylab = "Distance")
```

Returns me a single plot, with proper labels but only one boxplot. I need to divide the plots based on Control vs Treatment, and cannot figure out how.

Here is the data set I am working with

[image: Here is the data set I am working with]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No Images for data. Please post data in your question. Use this: `dput(s2040_W20_fishjump)`

Comment: @Sathish you do not see the data? It is the big table. I am unsure what to use dput(s2040_W20_fishjump) for

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow this, so it will help others to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tilda:

```
boxplot(s2040_W20_fishjump$Distance ~ s2040_W20_fishjump$Treatment, main = "Fish Jump Distance", xlab = "Control vs Treatment", ylab = "Distance")
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please mark the answer as the solution so the question is marked as answered.